# method object is not subscriptable Python

Tags: python

Running into a `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

```
import csv
import requests
import json

req = requests.get(url="https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getcontests?sport=NHL")
req.raise_for_status()
data = req.json()

for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
    draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
    req2 = requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/" + str(draftgroupid) + "/draftables?format=json")
    data2 = req2.json

    for i, player_info in enumerate(data2['draftables'][0]):
        date = player_info['competition']['startTime']
        print(date)
```

The draftgroupid's Output:

```
16901
16905
16902
16903
```

I'm wondering if its possibly the second while loop?

Comment: `req2.json` is a method, you aren't calling it

Comment: "I'm wondering if its possibly the second while loop?". Your code doesn't contain any while loops.

Comment: Its for `for i, player_info in enumerate(data2['draftables'][0]):`

Comment: When you leave off the parentheses at the end of a function name as in `data2 = req2.json`, you end up getting _the method object itself_, instead of the _result_ of calling the method.

Comment: `data2 = req2.json` assigns the `json` method to `data2` variable. To call method you should include `()` so that its `req2.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the json method, So your code should be changed as follows.

```
import csv
import requests
import json

req = requests.get(url="https://www.draftkings.com/lobby/getcontests?sport=NHL")
req.raise_for_status()
data = req.json()

for i, contest in enumerate(data['DraftGroups']):
    draftgroupid = contest['DraftGroupId']
    req2 = requests.get(url="https://api.draftkings.com/draftgroups/v1/draftgroups/" + str(draftgroupid) + "/draftables?format=json")
    data2 = req2.json() # Note that this line was changed

    for i, player_info in enumerate(data2['draftables']): # Removed [0]
        date = player_info['competition']['startTime']
        print(date)
```

Comment: after making your suggested change i receive a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` for this line `date = player_info['competition']['startTime']`

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson Probably, player_info is not a dictionary. Use the `type` method to check the type of the player_info. i.e: `print(type(player_info))`. If the output is not `dict` then you can't use the above syntax.

Comment: thanks, its a str.. How would I edit that for a str class

Comment: Show the output of print(player_info) and then I may be able to help

Comment: `date = player_info['competition']['startTime']
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Add the `print(player_info)` before that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161385/discussion-between-pubudu-dodangoda-and-michael-t-johnson).

Comment: `for i, player_info in enumerate(data2['draftables'][0]):`  This is what is before it